# RSelenium Scraping a Dynamic Table with Empty Spaces

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to scrape the data in the table on this website: https://www.iea.org/data-and-statistics/data-tables?country=WORLD

I am using RSelenium and I am obtaining the information that I am looking for. The problem is that the table on the website is having empty elements, which are not indicated as such in the text output that I end up with. As a result, I cannot replicate the original table in R.

Can you think of any way through which I can scrape the table and replicate it in R?

Thanks for your support. Original code is provided below.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)

driver <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                              chromever =
                                system2(command = "wmic",
                                        args = 'datafile where name="C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe" get Version /value',
                                        stdout = TRUE,
                                        stderr = TRUE) %>%
                                stringr::str_extract(pattern = "(?<=Version=)\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.") %>%
                                magrittr::extract(!is.na(.)) %>%
                                stringr::str_replace_all(pattern = "\\.",
                                                         replacement = "\\\\.") %>%
                                paste0("^",  .) %>%
                                stringr::str_subset(string =
                                                      binman::list_versions(appname = "chromedriver") %>%
                                                      dplyr::last()) %>%
                                as.numeric_version() %>%
                                max() %>%
                                as.character())

remote_driver <- driver[["client"]] 
remote_driver$navigate("https://www.iea.org/data-and-statistics/data-tables?country=WORLD")

out <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "class", value="m-data-table")

data <- out$getElementText() 
data <- gsub ("\n", ";", data)
data <- strsplit(data,";")
data <- gsub ("ktoe","Ktoe",  data[[1]])
data <- gsub (pattern="\\s+([a-z])", replacement="\\_\\U\\1", perl=TRUE, data)
data <- strsplit(data," ")
data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to scrape the inner HTML, instead of the inner text:

```
dtab <- out$getElementAttribute("innerHTML")

result <- dtab[[1]] %>%
  
  # convert from html table to data frame
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  rvest::html_table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  
  # remove the "ktoe" row
  filter(row_number() != 1) %>% 
  
  # convert to ASCII encoding
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~iconv(.x, "utf-8", "ASCII", sub = ""))) %>%
  
  # convert all except first column to integers
  mutate(across(-one_of("Var.1"),
                as.integer))
```

Result:

```
> tibble::glimpse(result)
Rows: 28
Columns: 12
$ Var.1              <chr> "Production", "Imports", "Exports", "International mari...
$ Coal               <int> 3893679, 829289, -879689, NA, NA, -4954, 3838326, -1156...
$ Crude.oil          <int> 4552548, 2479487, -2440069, NA, NA, -6450, 4585516, -23...
$ Oil.products       <int> NA, 1396839, -1488672, NA, NA, 3316, -88517, 261068, 95...
$ Natural.gas        <int> 3293124, 985018, -1019823, NA, NA, 3276, 3261595, NA, -...
$ Nuclear            <int> 706814, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 706814, NA, NA, -703393, -3...
$ Hydro              <int> 362332, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 362332, NA, NA, -362332, NA...
$ Wind..solar..etc.  <int> 286377, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 286377, NA, -42, -233459, -...
$ Biofuels.and.waste <int> 1324214, 29259, -25250, NA, NA, -1096, 1327127, NA, -11...
$ Electricity        <int> NA, 62626, -62373, NA, NA, NA, 253, NA, -5139, 1931734,...
$ Heat               <int> 2062, 6, -2, NA, NA, NA, 2066, NA, 3966, -894, 255095, ...
$ Total              <int> 14421151, 5782524, -5915877, NA, NA, -5909, 14281889, 2...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. I had also started looking at going for the HTML, but I didnt manage to get it this neat. 

One comment, replicating your code on my machine runs into an read_xml error, as it does not accept dtab being a list. I had to go via for dtab <- as.character(out$getElementAttribute("innerHTML")).

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. the input shld have been dtab[[1]]. Have edited my answer.